# How many ways are there to order a baseball lineup with a restriction related on two players?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:
Suppose that we have a baseball team with $9$ players. Due to union rules, in the batting
order the person playing first base must bat near the spot the person playing second base.
That is, if the person playing first base bats in position $i$ and the person playing
second base bats in position $j$ then the following statement must be true:
$$ |i - j| \leq 2 $$
How many possible batting orders are there?

Answer:
Let $c$ be the count we seek.
Call the person playing first base $A$ and the person playing second base $B$. If $A$
bats first (e.g. in position $1$ ) then person $B$ must bat in either position
$2$ or $3$. Let $c_1$ be the number of valid batting orders with player $A$ batting first.
$$ c_1 = 2(7!) $$
Let $c_2$ be the number of valid batting orders with player $A$ batting second.
$$ c_2 = 3(7!) $$
Let $c_3$ be the number of valid batting orders with player $A$ batting third.
$$ c_3 = 4(7!) $$
Let $c_4$ be the number of valid batting orders with player $A$ batting third.
$$ c_4 = 4(7!) $$
Let $c_8$ be the number of valid batting orders with player $A$ batting first.
$$ c_8 = 3(7!) $$
Let $c_9$ be the number of valid batting orders with player $A$ batting first.
$$ c_9 = 2(7!) $$
\begin{align*}
c &= c_1 + c_2 + 5( 4(7!)) + c_8 + c_9 \\
c &= 2(7!) + 3(7!) + 5( 4(7!)) + 3(7!) + 2(7!) \\
c &= 30( 7!) = 30(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) \\
c &= 151200
\end{align*}
Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your answer is correct. Another approach -

a) If both of them are batting adjacent to each other i.e. $|i - j| = 1$:
There are $2$ ways for their own batting order and then considering both of them together, there are $8!$ ways to arrange the batting order with $7$ other players.

So number of batting orders = $2 \cdot 8!$

b) If both are batting with exactly one batter between them i.e. $|i - j| = 2$: Again there are $2$ ways to order them, $7$ ways to decide who bats between them and then considering three of them together, there are $7!$ ways to arrange the batting order with $6$ other players.

So number of batting orders = $2 \cdot 7 \cdot 7!$

That leads to total number of batting orders as $~2 \cdot 8! + 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 7! = 151200$

Comment: In your post, you wrote:  $2 \cot 8!$. Did you mean  $2 \cdot 8!$ ?

Comment: @Bob yes, I correct now. Thanks.